# Oracle: error using DMBS_IJOBS

Tags: oracle, jobs

I've got the following error using the following code:

```
BEGIN
    sys.dbms_ijob.run(25950);
   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN others
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
      RAISE;
END;

ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.DBMS_IJOB' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're not running this as SYS.  Either you need to run it as SYS or you need a DBA to grant you execute privileges on the package.

Answer (score 2):

While @APC is correc that this is a permissions issue, I would strongly question why you are using the `DBMS_IJOB` package in the first place.  It is an undocumented, internal package, not something that should generally be used by developers.  And there is a perfectly good `RUN` procedure in the public, documented `DBMS_JOB` package that you can use instead

```
BEGIN
  dbms_job.run( 25950 );
  commit;
END;
/
```

There is no reason to use the internal, undocumented package when the public, documented package has a method to do what you want.

Comment: I need to run a JOB owned by a schema from another schema. The JOB already exists and I can grant everything. How can I solve?

Comment: @Gik25 - Can you create a procedure in the schema that owns the job that executes the job and grant `EXECUTE` access on that procedure to the user that needs to run the job?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a package called `DBMS_IJOB` in Oracle Database. It should be `DBMS_JOB`.

Comment: DBMS_IJOB is a valid package name, it's just undocumented